# Mockito - Accessing private/autowired fields for verify()

Tags: spring, testing, mocking, mockito, facade

So I am new to Mockito for testing facades. So basically I want to check, if a method of Service gets called once.

Here would be a simplified example

My Service

```
public class Service {
    public int myMethod(int index, int number) {
        if (index<4){
            index = index + number;
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

My Facade:

```
public class Facade {

    private Service service;

    public void method(){
        int i = service.myMethod(4, 2);
    }

}
```

and finally my Test:

```
public class FacadeTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private Facade classUnderTest;

    @Mock (name="service")
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        verify(classUnderTest, times(1)).service.myMethod(4,2);
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to use Getter/Setter-methods in my Facade to return the Service, but I want to do it, without doing that.

Is it possible, in the way I want to, without doing any change to the Facade?

And is there a difference, when I have a Spring-project and used @Autowired for the service variable inside the Facade?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `classUnderTest` in your test method with `service` and be done. You can only verify invocations on a mock not the class under tests (as that isn't controlled by Mockito).

Comment: You don't need any getter, since the service that is injected and used by the facade is the `private Service service;`. So you have access to it, and can verify its method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Using @InjectMocks will inject your annotated @Mock service in your facade.
So you don't need any getter or setter for your test.

It seems you forgot to call method in your test.
Try with this :

```
@Test
public void test(){
    classUnderTest.method();
    verify(service, times(1)).service.myMethod(4,2);
}
```

Using @Autowired service in your facade will have no impact on your test since spring is not used in it. Spring will inject the right bean when you'll run your application.